# Pivot table expand and substract or Show/Hide Details using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to hide details of the pivot table column using the below command.
Can Some one let me know the mistake?

Thx.

```
     For Each c In Range("A1:A20000")
         With c
             If Left(.Value, 2) = "FA" Then ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Ref 1").PivotItems( _
        "*").ShowDetail = False
             End With
     Next c
```

Comment: Do you get an error?  What error is it?

Comment: Unable to get the PivotTables property of the Worksheet class..

Comment: Are you sure the active sheet has a pivot table with that name?  Try `ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)` if there's only one table on the worksheet.

Comment: Now it comes with an error 
 
 
Unable to get the PivotItems property of the PivotField class

Comment: Maybe you don't have a pivot field named "Ref 1" ?

Comment: Definitely, Ref 1 is correct...
When I remove Pivot Items it actually collapse whole table...
I think the way I pick PivotItems is the problem :(

Comment: I don't think you can use a wildcard like that - you may have to loop over them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72102/discussion-between-isu-and-tim-williams).

Comment: For Each c In Range("A1:A20000")
             With c
                 If Left(.Value, 2) = "FA" Then ActiveSheet.PivotTables    ("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Ref 1").PivotItems( _
        "FA********").ShowDetail = False
                 End With
         Next c
 

The references I need to collapse start with FA, when I put 8 * marks it didn't work either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the silly mistake

```
Dim c As Range
     For Each c In myfile.Sheets(3).Range("A1:A20000")
         With c
            If Left(c.Value, 2) = "FA" Then ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Ref 1").PivotItems(c.Value).ShowDetail = False
        End With
     Next
```